# DataTables Export To Excel Button Not Always Showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table which I'm converting into a datatable, everything works fine except for the fact that the excel button doesn't always show up. It's a flip of a coin, sometimes I refresh and the button is there, other times I refresh and the button isn't there.

Here's my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

```
$("#finalDocsTable").DataTable({
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    buttons: ["excelHtml5"],
});
```

Comment: when it doesn't show, what errors are appearing in the console tab of F12 developer tools?  or on the network tab (resources not loading) ?

Comment: Do you need to load two button scripts? 1.6.5/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js and 1.6.5/js/buttons.html5.min.js?

Comment: There are not errors and all files are loading

Comment: We'll need a reproduceable example in order to provide help.